# Listener for Leaderboard in Google game services

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have setup leaderboard using the google game services. I am using the following statement for submitting the statistics after finishing the game.

```
Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(mHelper.getApiClient(),leaderBoardIdForHits,
totalChanceTaken);
```

### Question :

There may be situation that there will not be the internet services or some failure during the execution of the above submit statement. Also on successful submit of the statistics I need to show a Toast like "Statistics updated". I would like to know if there is any listener method for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define this class:

```
class myLeaderBoardSubmitScoreCallback implements ResultCallback<SubmitScoreResult> {
            @Override
            public void onResult(SubmitScoreResult res) {
                if (res.getStatus().getStatusCode() == 0) {
                    // data sent successfully to server.
                    // display toast.
                }
            }
        }
```

Then submit your score like this:

```
Games.Leaderboards.submitScoreImmediate(mHelper.getApiClient(),leaderBoardIdForHits,
totalChanceTaken).setResultCallback(new myLeaderBoardSubmitScoreCallback());
```

So know when you submit a score, a `ResultCallback` is set, which is delivered when a leaderboard score has been submitted. And if it has been successfully delivered to the server, display your toast.

Comment: what are the possible values for SubmitScoreResult.res and its meaning

Comment: What is the difference between submitScoreImmediate and submitScore

Comment: Here is submitscoreresult: http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/leaderboard/Leaderboards.SubmitScoreResult.html According to the documentation, **submitScore** is for *fire-and-forget* score uploads where you don't want to be notified of the results of submitting the score. **SubmitScoreImmediate** provides a callback o n the other hand, for when you do want to know the results of submitting a score, which is your case.